# Can a full disk cause network issues in linux?

Tags: linux, rabbitmq

I was running a RabbitMQ server on my Linux machine, when my disk became full I couldn't make any more connection requests to my rabbitMQ server, when I cleaned up the disk, the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible.

At lot of daemon do access logging. If the disk is full it might happen that logging fails and no more network requests are possible.

*Side note:*
If a daemon filled the disk with a log file, it might not be enough to delete the log file. You might need to restart/reload the daemon as the file isn't actually deleted while it is opened.